How to Create a Custom Hibernate SQL Dialect Compatible with Cloudera Impala (Hibernate 6.2.2.Final)
I am trying to create a custom Hibernate SQL dialect for Cloudera Impala. I'm using Hibernate 6.2.2.Final, and I need to ensure that the generated SQL for pagination uses the syntax LIMIT ... OFFSET ....
Problem
Currently, my custom dialect generates queries with the following (incorrect) syntax:
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    ...
WHERE
    ...
ORDER BY
    ...
OFFSET ... ROWS FETCH FIRST ... ROWS ONLY

Instead, I want the generated query to look like this:
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    ...
WHERE
    ...
ORDER BY
    ...
LIMIT ...
OFFSET ...

Current Implementation
Here is the custom ImpalaDialect I have created so far:
package br.work.config;

import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitHandler;
import org.hibernate.query.spi.Limit;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ImpalaDialect extends Dialect {

    public ImpalaDialect() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public LimitHandler getLimitHandler() {
        return new LimitHandler() {
            @Override
            public String processSql(String sql, Limit limit) {
                StringBuilder modifiedSql = new StringBuilder(sql);

                // Add LIMIT
                if (limit.getMaxRows() != null) {
                    modifiedSql.append(" limit ").append(limit.getMaxRows());
                }

                // Add OFFSET
                if (limit.getFirstRow() != null) {
                    modifiedSql.append(" offset ").append(limit.getFirstRow());
                }

                return modifiedSql.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean supportsLimit() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean supportsOffset() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean supportsLimitOffset() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void setMaxRows(Limit limit, PreparedStatement statement) throws SQLException {
            }

            @Override
            public int bindLimitParametersAtEndOfQuery(Limit limit, PreparedStatement statement, int index) throws SQLException {
                return index;
            }

            @Override
            public int bindLimitParametersAtStartOfQuery(Limit limit, PreparedStatement statement, int index) throws SQLException {
                return index;
            }
        };
    }
}

Question
What am I missing in my implementation to ensure Hibernate generates the correct SQL syntax with LIMIT ... OFFSET ... instead of OFFSET ... ROWS FETCH FIRST ... ROWS ONLY?
Any help or guidance on properly configuring the custom dialect for Impala would be greatly appreciated.
